# if and else statment not working (javascript) (html)

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript bit:

```
 function emptyF(){
        var x = document.getElementById("get");
        if(x.value.match("")){
            alert("missing fields");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

html bit:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="home.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" id="get" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="username" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['name'];?>" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" onclick="emptyF()" name="submit"  value="Log In" />
```

when i type something into the text box and click submit i get the alert, the alert is only supposed to come up if there was nothing entered, but this makes the alert come whether there is something or not.

Comment: Use only `return document.getElementById('get').value.trim() !== '';`

Comment: `x.value.match("")` should probably be `x.value === ""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare the value to the empty string, just compare it directly:

```
if (x.value === "")
```

The `.match()` function will coerce its argument into a regular expression, and every string will match the empty string.

Comment: @CodeNewbie the `onclick` should be `onclick="return emptyF()"`

Comment: nevermind it decided to work after a few minutes of staring at the code. ill keep the return bit in mind, but all is good for now. thanks.